# How to query StarDict (.dict) files using .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any API to query stardict (*.dict) dictionary files in .NET?
I'm using this for a dictionary look up in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is an API written in  dot Net, but I found one in Java at 
http://code.google.com/p/toolkits/
I think you can find some tools to convert it to C# codes. (this API referenced JZlib, and I hope dot net zip libraries are compatible with it)

Comment: here is direct link: http://toolkits.googlecode.com/svn-history/r74/trunk/android/YAStarDict/src/com/googlecode/toolkits/